# YouTube change Channel Banners

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When I request a change of banner for a YouTube channel, I get an error:
"googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/channelBanners/insert?alt=json&uploadType=resumable returned "Channel banner validation failed. This error can occur because the channel banner image is too large or is not accepted file type."

I tried various files from 150 kb to 2 mb, but the error still appears. Sometimes with the same file - it loads.
Perhaps this depends on the frequency of the channel banner change request? But I did not find the query frequency limit in the documentation.

Comment: You should explain what you did to get that error.

Comment: I have a Python script that works with the Youtube Api v3
Here is the log of his work - [link](http://joxi.ru/vAW8z5CkYGajrW.jpg)

Comment: What are the resolutions of the images you tried ?